# Int64 to NUMBER(18) ID conversion error

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, oracle10g

I'm using Fluent NHibernate as the ORM layer to my Oracle 10g database and am using a before insert trigger to create a unique id (with a sequence) when a record is inserted.

```
-- Within the trigger
SELECT myseqgen.nextval into :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
```

The id property in code is a long (Int64) which can't be changed to decimal to better match what we have in the database (common library).  I've mapped this as follows:

```
this.Id(x => x.Id, "ID")
    .CustomSqlType("NUMBER(18)")
    .CustomType(typeof(IdCustomType))
    .GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();
```

While I have created a custom type for this property, I don't think I should need it because in the database, the ID is configured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "SOME_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE" 
    ("ID" NUMBER(18,0), -- 18 means "anything up to 64 bit integer"
    ...
```

What's interesting however, is that inside the NullSafeSet method of my IdCustomType class, the "value" parameter is being passed as a decimal.

...not only that but upon checking NHProf, the insert statement worryingly becomes:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
        (COL_ONE,
         COL_TWO,
         COL_THREE,
         COL_FOUR,
         COL_FIVE,
         COL_SIX,
         COL_SEVEN)
VALUES      ('param one' /* :p0 */,
         'param two' /* :p1 */,
         NULL /* :p2 */,
         'param three' /* :p3 */,
         TIMESTAMP '2012-01-01 00:00:00.00' /* :p4 */,
         '22' /* :p5 */,
         '''81189'' [Type: String (5)], :nhIdOutParam = NULL' /* :p6 */)  -- WHAT!?
returning ID into :nhIdOutParam
```

After the insert statement, an automatic select of my concurrency identifier is invoked:

```
SELECT someRow_.CONCURRENCY_COL as CON_2_1_
FROM   MY_TABLE someRow_
WHERE  someRow_.ID = 5836738 /* :p0 */
```

...nothing is found.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: have you checked that it is successful inserted?

Answer (score 0):

oracle uses the syntax `returning ID into :nhIdOutParam` to place the generated ID into an out parameter called nhIdOutParam which NH supplies to the command to get the id after the insert completes.

Comment: But this bit?
'''81189'' [Type: String (5)], :nhIdOutParam = NULL' /* :p6 */
p6 should just be '81189', nothing more...  I can see why NHibernate's generating the standard "into" syntax but not why it's adding that extra info for p6!

Comment: maybe the output you are seeing is incorrect because it also writes the out parameter to the query even if it is out not in. have you tried executing the generated select directly to oracle to see if its inserted or not?